# laravel and json array

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel

I am using laravel 5.3 and angularjs
I submit json from my angularjs like below

```
{"grc":{"id":1},"floatingGrcs":[{"days":"10","units":"100"},{"days":"20","units":"200"}]}
```

I accept this array from my laravel controller like below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   //how to extract $request object in here
}
```

I don't know how to extract submitted json array in laravel controller

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard `json_decode()`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->someJson);
}
```

You can look at all available data with `dd($request->all());`

Answer (score 2):

The common-case is that there is no need to post json-encoded data through Angular.

To submit something with Angular, you should use, for example:

```
$http.post('api/something', {"grc":{"id":1},"floatingGrcs": [..]})
```

And then there is no need to decode json on the Laravel side:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request->all();     // to get all fields
   $request->grc->id;   // to get a specific field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer with below code. But i am not sure

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
```

is this above line of code secure or not.

```
public function store()
    {

        $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) 
        {
            if($key == "grc")
            {
                $grc_id = $value["id"];
            }
            elseif($key == "floatingGrcs")
            {
                foreach ($value as $floating) 
                {
                    $days = $floating["days"];

                }
            }

        }
```